# GCC says "syntax error before numeric constant" in generated header file from bison

Tags: gcc, enums, bison, flex-lexer

When I compile my .y file with bison parser.y -d -t and then include the parser.tab.h file in my flex file, gcc says "error: syntax error before numeric constant." It's referencing line 32, which is the first line in the enum of yytokentype.

```
enum yytokentype {
   BREAK = 258,
   ... }
```

The error is about the line "BREAK = 258." I honestly don't know why this is happening--I would really like to use the generated yylval and I need it from this header file. Even if I declared yytokentype like this in my flex file, I would get the same error. Anything I could be doing wrong?

Comment: I'm guessing there is a redefinition of `BREAK` somewhere above the errored line. The `-E` flag to gcc is good for ferreting these problems out.

Answer (score 20, accepted):

Is `BREAK` defined somewhere else in your code?  I get a similar error from the following toy example:

```
#define BREAK 10
enum yytokentype {
    BREAK = 258
};
```

Build example:

```
$ cc -c file.c 
file.c:4: error: expected identifier before numeric constant
```

Comment: Hmm? That example will fail with or without the `#define` because of the semicolon.

Comment: Yep... That's the issue. I checked all of my #includes and found it in one of them. Thanks for the help to both of you.

Comment: @Kinopiko, oops, should have copy/pasted instead of retyping.  Fixed now.

Answer (score 6):

Presumably BREAK is already defined somewhere in the flex output file, so after the preprocessor runs you are getting a statement like 99 = 258 or something. Try looking at the output of `cpp yy.lex.c` or `gcc -E yy.lex.c`. I looked at a flex output file but did not find BREAK anywhere in it, only YY_BREAK.